# Filter a Range of Dates with a String of Days

Tags: c#, datetime, filter

I'm working with a collection of DateTime with all dates from Date A to Date B.
I will be handed a string which looks like 1234567, 1 is sunday, 2 is tuesday, etc.

Now, imagine I want to filter my dates collection using a string with the above configuration and we get the string 1004007, meaning we will have to filter our DateTime collection to only have dates which occur on a sunday, on a wednesday and a saturday.

How can I read the whole string, figure out which days I will be filtering from and then dynamically filter my collection according to those days of the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
List<DateTime> dates = ...;
string filter = "1004007";

List<DateTime> filteredDates = dates.Where(d =>
    filter.Contains(((int)d.DayOfWeek + 1).ToString())).ToList();
```

Or, if you like, you can first construct a list of days that are your filter rather than just using the `String.Contains` function. If your list of dates is very large, doing this work up front could help performance:

```
List<DateTime> dates = ...;
string filter = "1004007";
var daysOfWeek = filter.Distinct().Where(c => c != '0')
                       .Select(c => (DayOfWeek)(int.Parse(c.ToString()) - 1))

List<DateTime> filteredDates = (from d in dates
                                join dw in daysOfWeek on d.DayOfWeek equals dw
                                select d).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is quite complete and explains the solution well.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the day of the week to an integer, then a string, and use Contains to see if it is in your input string:

```
string days = "1004007";
var result = datetimes
   .Where(dt => days.Contains(((int)dt.DayOfWeek + 1).ToString()));
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how I can loop through the string which says what days of the week we are filtering through to then filter the range of dates.

Comment: @Hallaghan: You don't have to loop through the string. Contains does that for you.

Comment: So it actually detects those numbers as being days inside the contains and filters the dates by them?

Comment: @Hallaghan: It finds the day of the week for each date time, converts it to an integer between 1 and 7, then converts the integer to a string (a single character). It then tests to see if this character is contained in your input string using string.Contains.